# Is there an sbt plugin to get dependencies like in Gemfile?

Tags: sbt, dependency-management

With dependency management tools like rvm, dart's pub, etc, you can specify a dependency without a specific version. I will get the latest versions of each dependency an produce a baseline artifact. This artifact contains each dependency with their latest version at the time you ran the command.

With sbt I find myself doing this step manually by looking at the maven repo. Is their a sbt plugin that does that already ?

For exemple with dart's pub you can do this.

[pubspec.yaml](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/pubspec.yaml)

```
...
dependencies:
  args: '>=0.10.0 < 0.11.0'
  analyzer: '>=0.13.0 <0.14.0'
  barback: '>=0.11.1 <0.14.0'
...
```

[pubspec.lock](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/pubspec.lock)

```
packages:
  analyzer:
    description: analyzer
    source: hosted
    version: "0.13.6"
  args:
    description: args
    source: hosted
    version: "0.10.0+2"
  barback:
    description: barback
    source: hosted
    version: "0.12.0"
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the answer from @darko-cerdic

You can specify `latest` as a revision number. Eg:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.derby" % "derby" % "latest.release"
```

For more details check out ivy documentation:

http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.3.0/ivyfile/dependency.html#revision

If you want, you can manually specify `dependencyOverrides` to force a specific library version:

```
dependencyOverrides ++= Seq( "org.apache.derby" % "derby" % "1.0.0")
```

Note that in SBT 1.+ the dependencyOverrides are specified as a Seq, whereas in prior versions it was specified as a Set.

Using the sbt-lock plugin, you can lock the current version for all of your dependencies, so that your CI system can use a stable set of dependencies.  It generates a set of `dependencyOverrides` based on the current set of resolved `libraryDependencies`.  This gives you behavior that is similar to a Gemfile.lock.

https://github.com/tkawachi/sbt-lock

Answer (score 4):

You can specify `latest` as a revision number. Eg:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.derby" % "derby" % "latest.release"
```

For more details check out ivy documentation:

http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.3.0/ivyfile/dependency.html#revision

Comment: +1 It look like it's haft the awnser, because it won't lock the version.